# Process Pool Executor accumulates GPU memory

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing

I am training and evaluating multiple Deep Learning Networks in parallel, using `Process Pool Executor`

To achieve this, I first create some configurations, which are the input for the training function. As a short example, a config could be a list of, for example, the number of hidden layers, the learning rate and the number of classes., which the network should classify.

```
samples = [[1, 0.001, 5], [2, 0.0001, 7], [3, 0.001, 6]]
```

The training function simply fits the model w.r.t to these configurations. So, to create the pool I use the following code:

```
futures = []
n_workers = 3
with ProcessPoolExecutor(n_workers) as pool:
    for config in samples:
        future = pool.submit(training_function, config)
        futures.append(future)
```

Then, I wait until all processes did run

```
completed, incomplete = wait(futures)
assert not any(incomplete)
```

Intuitively, I think the issue could arise here, because I accumulate all processes, but I am not so sure.

Afterwards, I want to gather the results, i.e. the validation error of each network:

```
results = []
for future in futures:
    val_error = future.result()
    results.append(val_error)
```

This process works fine, with the exception that my GPU memory accumulates and does not get freed. In other words, using `nvidia-smi`,  the GPU memory usage only increases, until I run out of memory. As an example, at the very start the output of `nvidia-smi` might look something like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1074      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                249MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1495      G   cinnamon                           38MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1708      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          151MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2899      C   python                           1790MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2900      C   python                           1158MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2901      C   python                            594MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After some iterations:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1074      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                262MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1495      G   cinnamon                           46MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1708      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox          179MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2899      C   python                           4214MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2900      C   python                           6072MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2901      C   python                           8810MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

which is very close to the capacity of my GPU. Any ideas how I can free memory or which other method I could use?